# grouping image using colorbox and jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

i am creating a plugin on the top of colorbox modalpopup.

jquery plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {

  $.fn.pop= function(options) {

    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.pop.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var o = options;
      var obj = $(this);
       obj.click(function() {
     obj.colorbox({height:o.h, width:o.w , iframe:true});       
   });       
    });
  };     
  $.fn.pop.defaults = {
    h: '60%',
 w: '60%'
  };
})(jQuery);
});
```

at the user level i just make them call
$(".classname").pop(); //if they need to optimize the length width they just give the nos

now my question is if i need to group image i got to do something like this.

```
$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
```

insted of this i need to call my function

```
$("a[rel='example1']").pop();
```

but it doesn't group itself. anyhelp will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

colorbox has a "rel" tag attribute: I'm not sure exactly off the top of my head but should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {

  $.fn.pop= function(options) {

    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.pop.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var o = options;
      var obj = $(this);
       obj.click(function() {
       // the following addition where o.r is options.rel = this.attr('rel');
       // or something like that
        obj.colorbox({height:o.h, width:o.w , iframe:true, rel:o.r});  
       });       
    });
  };     
  $.fn.pop.defaults = {
    h: '60%',
    w: '60%',
    r: 'group1'
  };
})(jQuery);
});
```

Also remember if you ajax in a link that has  your plugin will not pick it up by itself as it's leveraging colorbox and extending it but you're not changing the fact that it uses 'live' instead of 'delegate'. You may want to give that a little research...

and colorbox has great docs on relationships and grouping:
jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Please scroll down to settings... reading docs is never a waste of time as one can't find all the solutions on forums.